# Error oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed ONLY when running a Laravel COMMAND from the TERMINAL

Tags: oracle, laravel-artisan

I’m working with a Laravel application that’s running on a Linux machine with an Oracle instance. When I send a POST request to the application via the web server, the data is saved correctly to the database. However, when I try to run a specific Laravel command from the terminal ( php artisan command:exampleConect), I receive the following error:

`oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are set and point to the right directories.`

In order to check ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I have created a command with the following code:

```
$oracleHome = getenv('ORACLE_HOME');
$ldLibraryPath = getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH');

$this->info("ORACLE_HOME: $oracleHome");
$this->info("LD_LIBRARY_PATH: $ldLibraryPath");
```

I have implemented this on my local machine (where my command works), but both variables appear to be empty.

Could anyone suggest what else I should try? Could I have made a mistake in my assumptions or taken something for granted that I shouldn’t have?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.